# Is there any datatype with which I can declare a variable as constant in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, loopback

Right now I am working with loopback PostgreSQL. I have tried searching for it for a long time, but I am not getting any related results. There is no keyword/ datatype with which I can declare a variable constant.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the JavaScript library [LoopBack.io](https://loopback.io/): do you want to declare a variable in Javacript or PL/pgSQL?

Comment: I declared the variable. I would like to keep the variable value constant.

Comment: In Javascript or PL/pgSQL?

Comment: PL/pgSQL. and yes I was referring to JavaScript library Loopback.io. sorry for the incomplete answer earlier.

Comment: There is no such keyword in PL/pgSQL

Comment: Oh. I thought I must have missed it somewhere. Is there any chance I can do that with JavaScript file? Is it possible I declare a variable in PL/pgSQL and mark it constant from JavaScript file?